# How do I declare a default constructor for sub-class of abstract class?

Tags: java, class, constructor, abstract

The following doesn't work for me in Java. Eclipse complains that there is no such constructor. I've added the constructor to the sub-class to get around it, but is there another way to do what I'm trying to do?

```
public abstract class Foo {
    String mText;

    public Foo(String text) {
        mText = text;
    }  
}

public class Bar extends Foo {

}

Foo foo = new Foo("foo");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't instantiate `Foo` since it's abstract.

Instead, `Bar` needs a constructor which calls the `super(String)` constructor.

e.g.

```
public Bar(String text) {
   super(text);
}
```

Here I'm passing the `text` string through to the super constructor. But you could do (for instance):

```
public Bar() {
   super(DEFAULT_TEXT);
}
```

The `super()` construct needs to be the first statement in the subclass constructor.

Comment: Thanks. I meant 

Bar bar = new Bar("bar");

I have you solution implemented, but I wasn't sure if you HAD to implement the constructor in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate from an abstract class and that's what you are trying here. Are you sure that you didn't mean:

```
Bar b = new Bar("hello");
```

???